# Visualforce: Checkboxes selected in field set do not save to record

Tags: visualforce, repeat, fieldsets

I'm an Apex and Visualforce beginner with not much overall programming experience to boot.

I've been tasked with updating a VF page that needs to display a series of checkboxes defined in a field set. When the user clicks 'Save' on the page, the values of the selected checkboxes should be populated on a newly created record but that isn't what's happening.

I followed the Salesforce [Working with Field Sets docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) and was able to get the checkboxes to display on the page, but the selected values aren't being saved to the new record.

The VF page is using a standard controller for the custom object `c4g_Case_Note__c` with a custom controller in an extension. Here's the page def from the VF page:

```xml
<apex:page standardController="c4g_Case_Note__c" extensions="CaseNoteController" lightningStylesheets="true" sidebar="false" tabstyle="Case">
```

Here's the section in the page that references the field set, which is called Housing Topics:

```xml
<!--Housing Topics section-->
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Housing Topics" rendered="{!renderHousingTopics}">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.c4g_Case_Note__c.FieldSets.Housing_Topics}" var="f">
        <apex:inputField value="{!c4g_Case_Note__c[f]}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I assumed that using a standard controller and an `<inputField>` element meant that I wouldn't need to update the controller to save the fields. I should also note that the block above is inside a set of `<form>` tags.

Did I so something wrong in setting up the section, or do I have to somehow track the selected fields in the controller? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a public property in the `CaseNoteController` extension that exposes the current record? (assume it is called `theRec`, then try `<apex:inputField value="{!theRec[f]}" />`)

Comment: @cropredy -- That did it! The constructor creates a new object record called `caseNote`.  I updated the value for the input field to `{!caseNote[f]}` and the checkbox values now save as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per @cropredy , I needed to find a reference to the target record in the `CaseNoteController` constructor and update the VF page to use that reference.

I found that the constructor creates a new record:

```
caseNote = new c4g_Case_Note__c();
```

I updated the VF code to use that reference and the issue was resolved:

```xml
<!--Housing Topics section-->
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Housing Topics" rendered="{!renderHousingTopics}">
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.c4g_Case_Note__c.FieldSets.Housing_Topics}" var="f">
        <apex:inputField value="{!caseNote[f]}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```